# Use neo4j apoc.trigger.install to trigger a custom code written in Python

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I want to add a trigger to my neo4j so that when a new file is added, it will either execute a custom python code, or at the very least make an api call sending the information on the node created
Not sure how I should do this:

```
Something following this logic:
CALL apoc.trigger.install('neo4j', 'on create trigger',"UNWIND $createdNodes AS n
custom_function(n))
```

Comment: You can do your own APOC library then deploy it in your server. This is what we do in my company where we build in-house functions (APOC) for our customized use cases. Thanks.

Comment: @jose_bacoy [APOC](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/) is the name of an existing neo4j library. You probably meant to recommend the creation of [user-defined procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/). It is not clear how that would help. Can you share more details of your approach as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use try using [`apoc.load.jsonParams`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.load/apoc.load.jsonParams/) to make the API call from inside the trigger.

Assuming your endpoint was `foo.bar/baz` it would look something like this (sending a list of nodes created):

```
CALL apoc.trigger.install(
  'neo4j', 
  'MyTrigger', 
  "CALL apoc.load.jsonParams('https://foo.bar/baz', {method: 'POST'}, apoc.convert.toJson({'nodes': $createdNodes})) ",
  {phase: 'afterSync'})
```